# Adding "#" in front of the first 8 lines matching STRING

Tags: awk, sed, text-parsing

The question is a bit confusing so I will just show an example.

Let's say I have the following case:

```
$ grep -P "locus_tag\tM715_1000193188" Genome.tbl -B1 -A8
193188  193066  gene
            locus_tag   M715_1000193188
193188  193066  mRNA
            product hypothetical protein
            protein_id  gnl|CorradiLab|M715_1000193188
            transcript_id   gnl|CorradiLab|M715_mrna1000193188
193188  193066  CDS
        product hypothetical protein
        protein_id  gnl|CorradiLab|M715_1000193188
        transcript_id   gnl|CorradiLab|M715_mrna1000193188
```

I want to add "#" to the 8 lines following "locus_tag   M715_1000193188", so that my modified file will look like this:

```
193188  193066  gene
            locus_tag   M715_1000193188
#193188 193066  mRNA
#           product hypothetical protein
#           protein_id  gnl|CorradiLab|M715_1000193188
#           transcript_id   gnl|CorradiLab|M715_mrna1000193188
#193188 193066  CDS
#       product hypothetical protein
#       protein_id  gnl|CorradiLab|M715_1000193188
#       transcript_id   gnl|CorradiLab|M715_mrna1000193188
```

Essentially I have a file with ~3000 different locus tags and for 300 of these I need to comment out mRNA and CDS features, so the 8 lines following the locus_tag line.

Any possible way to do this with sed? There are other types of information in the file which need to be left untouched.

Thanks,
Adrian

Answer (score 3):

If you can use `awk`, this should do:

```
awk 'f&&f-- {$0="#"$0} /locus_tag/ {f=8} 1' file
193188  193066  gene
            locus_tag   M715_1000193188
#193188  193066  mRNA
#            product hypothetical protein
#            protein_id  gnl|CorradiLab|M715_1000193188
#            transcript_id   gnl|CorradiLab|M715_mrna1000193188
#193188  193066  CDS
#        product hypothetical protein
#        protein_id  gnl|CorradiLab|M715_1000193188
#        transcript_id   gnl|CorradiLab|M715_mrna1000193188
```

Comment: Nice, it works! How can I make the changes in the file directly? I need to do this 300 times so is there anyway to make changes to "file" directly every time I make an edit? Let's say I have a for loop in which $i is the locus name, the awk would look like this awk 'f&&f-- {$0="#"$0} /locus_tag\t$i/ {f=8} 1' file

Comment: To make `awk` update the original file do: `awk 'commands' file >tmp && mv tmp file`.  If you have `gawk` >= ` 4.1` you can use `gawk -i`

Comment: Or pass awk all the locus values and make all the changes in one pass over the input file.

Comment: I ran into a bit of trouble. Some locus numbers, for example M715_80001 are problematic because of partial matches to other locus numbers, such as M715_8000123 M715_80001654. How can I adjust this for an exact match? I tried adding a \n character, but it doesn't work awk 'f&&f-- {$0="#"$0} /locus_tag\tM715_80001\n/ {f=8} 1'

Comment: You can do: `awk 'f&&f-- {$0="#"$0} $1=="locus_tag" && $2=="M715_80001" {f=8} 1' file`

Answer (score 1):

sed supports range [Addresses](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Addresses) that can do what you want here.

```
sed -e '/locus_tag\tM715_1000193188/,+8s/^/#/' file
```

As noted in the comments this range address format is GNU sed specific.

Comment: I like it. Apart from that: sed understands `\t` directly. The `/pattern/,+8` form of ranges is GNU-specific; it might be prudent to make note of that.

Comment: This solution comments the 8 lines following the string as well as the line in which the string is found. Is it possible not to comment the line in which the string is found? Thanks

Comment: Hm... Good question. I'm not sure sed can do that easily. vim supports that sort of range though. You would need a label and a replacement test or something like that for sed I think.

Comment: Is there a way to also do this but for the 2 lines before the match? I tried -2s instead of +8s but that didn't work.

Comment: sed definitely cannot go backwards like that. I don't know that sed does "math" on ranges either. vim can do both of those things but isn't suitable for large files. You could do this with awk by keeping a sliding window of lines manually but I don't know of anything that can do this in a streaming fashion (possibly perl but I don't know).

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { split(tags,tmp); for (i in tmp) tagsA[tmp[i]] }
c&&c-- { $0 = "#" $0 }
($(NF-1) == "locus_tag") && ($NF in tagsA) { c=8 }
{ print }

$ awk -v tags="M715_1000193188 M715_1000193189 M715_1000193190" -f tst.awk file
193188  193066  gene
            locus_tag   M715_1000193188
#193188  193066  mRNA
#            product hypothetical protein
#            protein_id  gnl|CorradiLab|M715_1000193188
#            transcript_id   gnl|CorradiLab|M715_mrna1000193188
#193188  193066  CDS
#        product hypothetical protein
#        protein_id  gnl|CorradiLab|M715_1000193188
#        transcript_id   gnl|CorradiLab|M715_mrna1000193188
```

Just list all 300 of the locus tags values you care about as shown above for 3 examples.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/.*/\\#locus_tag\\s*&#,+9{\\#locus_tag\\s*&#n;s|^|#|}/' tag_file |
sed -i -f - file
```

This creates a sed script from a tag file and prepends `#` to the eight lines following a match on the tag.